# Display fields depend on user role

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i have a page that shows products and each product has 2 price one for regular customers and one for cooperation that is cheaper and i want to show second price for users that are in "Cooperation" role and show first price for other users.
i am using repeater and in repeater i used

```
<%# Eval("UnitPrice") %>
```

now i want to use

```
<%# Eval("CooperationPrice") %>
```

if user role is "cooperation".
something like this in c#

```
if(User.IsInRole("cooperation")){//show second price}else{//show first price}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C# [Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) like this:-

```
<%# User.IsInRole("cooperation")) ? Eval("CooperationPrice") : Eval("UnitPrice") %>
```